# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ifs.employees' doesn't exist Laravel Error

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating simple crud system on Laravel. I got the error on `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ifs.employees' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from`employees`)`
this is the first time I creating the Laravel project.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('employee', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->Increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('age');
            $table->integer('salary');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**view page**
**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('employee.layout')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Laravel 6 CRUD Example from scratch - ItSolutionStuff.com</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('employee.create') }}"> Create New Product</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
             <th>Salary</th>
            <th width="280px">Action</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($Employee as $employee)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $employee->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $employee->age }}</td>
              <td>{{ $employee->salary }}</td>


            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('products.destroy',$employee->id) }}" method="POST">

                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('employee.show',$employee->id) }}">Show</a>

                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('employee.edit',$employee->id) }}">Edit</a>

                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>

    {!! $employee->links() !!}

@endsection
```

**EmployeeController**

```
class EmployeeController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $employee = Employee::latest()->paginate(5);

            return view('employee.index',compact('employee'))
                ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function create()
        {
            return view('employee.create');
        }

        /**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required',
                'age' => 'required',
                'salary' => 'required',
            ]);

            Product::create($request->all());

            return redirect()->route('employee.index')
                ->with('success','Employee created successfully.');





        }

        /**
         * Display the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  \App\Employee  $employee
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function show(Employee $employee)
        {
            return view('employee.show',compact('employee'));
        }
```

Comment: You are compacting a variable product but you want to return the employee variable. `compact('employee')`

Comment: i changed Undefined variable: Employee (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ifs\resources\views\employee\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 2):

You've created the table name as `employee` but when you called the model `Employee` it'll find in DB as `employees`

So, either change the name of the table as `employees` or define the name of `employee` in the model as `protected $table = 'employee'`.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'employee';

}
```

Check more [basic-usage](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage)

**Edit :-**

In the controller, you're getting `employees` data in the `index` method but you're not passing it in view file that's why you're getting the undefined error.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $employees = Employee::latest()->paginate(5);
    return view('employee.index',compact('employees'))
                ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

**View file**

```
@foreach ($employees as $employee)

@endforeach
```

Comment: after did this i got another error of Undefined variable: Employee (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ifs\resources\views\employee\index.blade.php)

Comment: @Javafiver Can you provide the code of your controller in your awnser

Comment: So have you `compact` or `passed` that Employee  data from controller?

Comment: you are calling `$Employee` variable in blade file so you need to set the data of Employee in controller and pass to the view file.

Comment: Undefined variable: employees (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ifs\resources\views\employee\index.blade.php) again displayed i correct every as u told

Comment: Check on which line are you getting this error. you need to debug it it's only undefined error.

Comment: Undefined variable: employees (0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204102/discussion-between-java-fiver-and-dilip-hirapara).

Comment: Select the answer if it'll resolved you question. Thank you.